# Migration from MySQL to MSSQL database

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, migration

I've a Joomla 3.6 project which is built on mysql db. I want to know how can I migrate to mssql db? Maybe someone could do step by step guide and suggest some tool for migration?

Answer (score 1):

You gonna have many problems with that. First of all almost all extensions run on MySQL and they are not prepared for MSSQL. Other thing is that Joomla! MySQL database is a bit complicated and can break after converting.

You can try it like this:

- Create a copy of your website files on other account, on that one we'll do the test
- Export website database from phpMyAdmin using a capability mode to MSSQL
- Import the database into your MSSQL server and create proper credentials
- Change db driver to mssql and credentials in `configuration.php` to your new credentials
- Enable system debug and pray